# Cut points from which to choose the best split in Decision Tree regressor with continious feature?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I understand,  that in the Decision Tree algorithm, when the splitting is decided, we choose the best split based on some criterion. And when you're looking for the best split, you have to iterate through some list of values. But it seems very computationally expensive to *consider every value of the feature* as the possible threshold (or, so called, cut point). Thus, there is a necessity for some *heuristic* for choosing these thresholds. For example, if we have continuous feature and categorical target (i.e, we are dealing with classification problem), we can do the following: sort dataset by given feature and consider for splitting only values, where target variable is changing it's value.

But what do you do if you have regression task, i.e. both feature and target are continuous variables? I realize, that I have to calculate, for example, the mean variance or mean median deviation in both branches for each split. But how do you decide *from which values you're choosing* you best split? People surely have came up with some optimal solution in order to avoid iterating over every value of the feature in the training set.

I've done some research, but most sources only focuses on different criteria and questions of *how* you determine whether your split is suitable. Which is not really answering my question.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404410/how-to-split-continous-attribute-in-cart-decision-tree-algorithm), but `Predictor` only suggests, that it can be done using the percentiles. And I think, that there is no guarantee, that this is how it *really done* in real life.

I've also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513511/decision-trees-choosing-thresholds-to-split-objects), but for me `geledek`'s answer is not very clear (obviously, dude just copy-pasted his answer from presentation, that he is referring to). I'm pretty much fine with the Method 1, but I would really appreciate if someone could explain Method 2 in more details. Or, perhaps, provide some different source or explanation of your own.

UPD: I've also looked up to the scikit-learn repo at GitHub, and found [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L466). I can't quite understand the overall code, but it seems that this particular line implies that thresholds are chosen as the averages of the neighboring feature values (which corresponds with the aforementioned Method 1 from the question above). Is that correct? I also don't understand this comment:  `# sum of halves is used to avoid infinite value`. How exactly does dividing by two prevent from getting infinite values? Don't you get infinity only when you are dividing by zero? Is dividing by two necessary, because this way we are getting average value (and not because we don't want to get infinitely)?